# Advanced lookup filter logic on Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, administration, sales

I have a business requirement (US) stating that when creating an opportunity record, I should be able to select in the `Account name` lookup field, only the accounts that either I own or in which I'm a team member.

In the lookup filter feature it is possible to filter account based on ownership, but for the Account team membership is not.

Is there any standard way of achieving so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Account OWD is public, then you can't do it.  If the OWD is private, then you don't need a lookup filter because the system automatically allows access to your team accounts.